# Difference between get instance() and get reference() in android studio..?

Tags: android, firebase

What is Difference between get instance() and get reference() in android studio which we use while saving or retrieving data from fire base..??

Answer (score 1):

> The entry point for accessing a Firebase Database. You can get an
>   instance by calling `getInstance().`
>
> To access a location in the database and read or write data, use
>   `getReference().`

**check doc here** 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase

Answer (score 0):

The difference is clear, **getInstance()** returns a new instance of the database object, while **getReference()** is a reference to an existing instance of the database object.

**getInstance()** is mainly used to create a new instance of the database object however the **getReference()** is used to reference an existing instance of the database object.